# FabricJS how to retreive data from on('mouse:move) function?

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, fabricjs

The button 'b' function returns 0 even tho console log from for-loop prints out all points correctly while during mouse move.

My wild guess is that it's because b.onclick is calling data from within the on('mouse:move) function but how would I get it otherwise?

https://jsfiddle.net/ehumkkpp/

[No change have been made between canvas.getPointer(o.e) 'for-loop' and Console.log(pointerPoints.length) yet, for some reason, it returns 0.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zu3gS.png)

```
    <canvas id="myCanvas" style="width: 500; height: 500"></canvas>
     <button id="button" class="btn btn-info"># 1</button>

var $ = function(id){return document.getElementById(id)};

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('myCanvas');
var b = $('button');

var isDown = false, pointerPoints;

canvas.on('mouse:over', function(e){ 

    canvas.isDrawingMode = true;    
});

canvas.on('mouse:down', function(o){    
    isDown = true;  
});

canvas.on('mouse:move', function(o){    

    var pointsPointer = [];

    if (isDown == true){

        var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
        var px = pointer.x; //o.e.layerX
        var py = pointer.y; //o.e.layerY

        pointsPointer.push({x:px, y:py});   
    };  
    pointerPoints = pointsPointer;  

    for(let i = 0; i < pointerPoints.length; i++){      
        console.log('Pointer ', pointerPoints[i]);
    };  
});
b.onclick = function(){
    console.log('Pointer ', pointerPoints.length);  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var getEl = function(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id)
};

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('myCanvas');
canvas.isDrawingMode = true;
var b = getEl('button');

var isDown = false,
    pointerPoints = [];

//canvas.on('mouse:over', function(e){ 
//});

canvas.on('mouse:down', function(o) {
    isDown = true;
});

canvas.on('mouse:move', function(o) {
    if (isDown == true) {
        var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
        var px = pointer.x; //o.e.layerX
        var py = pointer.y; //o.e.layerY
        pointerPoints.push({
            x: px,
            y: py
        });
    };
    //for(let i = 0; i < pointerPoints.length; i++){  
    //console.log('Pointer ', pointerPoints[i]);
    //}; 
});
canvas.on('mouse:up', function(o) {
    isDown = false;
})

b.onclick = function() {
    console.log('Pointer ', pointerPoints.length);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.18/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myCanvas" style="width: 500; height: 500"></canvas>
<button id="button" class="btn btn-info"># 1</button>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replaying but I think you misunderstood my question.
I know what this function does because I have written it myself, apart from on.('mouse:move') method itself of course, that's fabric's.

I'm not quite sure whether you run this code or not but look up, I have updated my question. Maybe this can clears up things for you.

Cheers

Comment: What you want to get from this?  Can you make it clear?

Comment: I want to get pointerPoints array data to use it with other functions,
for instance: value of 'point[28].x' and point[36].y

If that array's length equals 0, there's nothing inside of it right?

Comment: then you no need to create another array, just push to global and access the point anywhere you want, check that updated snippet.@dozobus

Comment: That's exactly what I've done first but I'm getting this:
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined".
hence global variable.

I really appreciate you are trying to help but it would be undoubtedly more efficient if you actually run this code and see for yourself what the heck is wrong with it. All this is just wild guessing. Cheers

Comment: You need to declare it before `pointerPoints = [];`.  Mark if it solves your problem

Comment: OMG I thought that if variable is declared as array and value of it assigned to new variable, the new one automatically becomes it. Which would make perfect sense. Anyway thanks for helping me.